# Confusion in analyzing Space complexity

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, space-complexity

I was solving questions on space complexity and When we talk about space complexity, we don't consider the space used by the input.but here in below code which I saw from a website ,isn't it should be O(1) , why they are saying its dependent on n ?? Please clarify iam confused

```
 int sum(int A[ ], int n)
{
   int sum = 0, i;
   for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
      sum = sum + A[i];
   return sum;
}
```

In the above piece of code it requires
'n*2' bytes of memory to store array variable 'a[ ]'
2 bytes of memory for integer parameter 'n'
4 bytes of memory for local integer variables 'sum' and 'i' (2 bytes each)
2 bytes of memory for return value.

That means, totally it requires '2n+8' bytes of memory to complete its execution. Here, the total amount of memory required depends on the value of 'n'. As 'n' value increases the space required also increases proportionately. This type of space complexity is said to be Linear Space Complexity.

Comment: Please paste the question as a text instead of picture.

Comment: Yes thanks I edited it can you please explain

Comment: It's O(1) space complexity, because space complexity measures additional space needed, and not the size of the input. Either the other website is wrong, or you're misrepresenting what it says.

Comment: @Paul Hankin can you tell me by giviing a simple example , my doubt is suppose n=100 in above program then A[1] = 0 , A[2] = 0 ,A[3]=0 ,,,.....A[100]= 0   so if n is increasing the space in memory is also increasing so it depends on n so why not O(n) and what is the extra space you are saying Iam confused please can you give a deep explanation with simple example.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various authors and web-sites use "space complexity" to mean different things, so you have to check the notation for the specific web-page.

https://www.studytonight.com/data-structures/space-complexity-of-algorithms
states that Space Complexity = Auxiliary Space + Input space
(I assume that is related to the site you used.)

https://theory.cs.princeton.edu/complexity/book.pdf
defines Space Complexity as excluding Input Space (and in that case input space is read-only), which seems more normal.

Comment: So which one should I follow??

Comment: If you take a course do as your professor/course material does.
Excluding inputs is the more common one.